# What exactly is DoubleBuffering?

Tags: c#, winforms

I know there are  two types of buffer: `front and back buffer`.

I know I should set the `DoubleBuffered` Property so that the controls don't flicker.

But, what are the other modules where we use `DoubleBuffered` Property?

Comment: while asking question,Dont add </br> to go to next line..You can simply just press Enter twice...

Comment: Front and back buffers are the same thing - a piece of reserved memory. Are you asking how double buffering works to eliminate flickering?

Comment: Not Exactly , But Yes , and mainly when we should use it ?

Comment: Also if your trying to reduce graphics artifacts like flicker, double buffering will not help with tearing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When drawing on the screen, if you do not double buffer it will draw directly to the screen as you are drawing each control, graphic, whatever. This causes the flickering because it actually has to repaint the whole screen each time a new object is drawn and modifies the view.

By enabling double buffering, it instead draws to an unseen buffer and when that buffer is done being drawn to, it takes that whole view and paints it to the screen in a single pass, eliminating the flicker.

It's called double buffering because, behind the scenes, what's happening is that you have 2 buffers, we'll call them A and B.  On the first pass, you draw to A and then switch the view to the A buffer which is painted on the screen.  On the second pass, since A is now the screen view, you draw to B and then switch the view to the B buffer. Rinse ans repeat. So you are just flipping back and forth between 2 buffers... you switch buffers because otherwise you would actually need A, B and a screen buffer that is copied to from A or B.  This is both slower because of the memory copy and requires 50% more RAM... bad idea.

Hope that explains what's happening better.

Comment: I believe most gui frameworks swap references between buffers, and don't actually copy the full frame when they swap. I know for certain directx works that way.

Comment: Isn't that what I said it was doing??

Comment: I Want to use double buffer for drawing, cause C# doesn't has a XOR PEN

Comment: @Adam I was just clarifying the "This is both slower because of the memory copy" line. I thought you meant physically coping the frame from one buffer to the other. If I misread I apologize. Also my name is Adam. High five.

Comment: Ahh, yeah, I just meant that is NOT how it's done and why. Should've clarified more.

Comment: Parkhid... you never really said *what* you want to do.  On controls, just set DoubleBuffered = true, and draw to the control.  Not really much else you need to do..

Answer (score 1):

Any time you want to draw something without the viewer seeing it before it is complete, you'd want to double buffer.

Comment: should I create bitmap to use the second buffer ? I mean , how can I save my drawings into second buffer?

Comment: Your tags say c# and java. The syntax will be different for each.

Comment: Typically you would use some framework-supported offscreen graphics context of some kind.  Looks like winforms supports this: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/winforms-tutorial-manage-your-own-double-buffering

Comment: It is not important  , I know both of them , pseudo code please if it is possible .

Comment: @Parkhid  - If you know both then this should be trivial.  If you want for instance to have a ListView control that was double buffered.  You would create your own class which inherited from ListView and set the DoubleBuffered property to true.

Answer (score 1):

Create two image buffers

Blit to one of them, it will be "Front" and present it to the screen

Now for each frame, Blit to the "Back" buffer, then swap it with the "front" so it is now the back and repeat.

This stops flicker by only presenting fully composed images to the screen.

Comment: It's a pretty simple idea once you understand exactly what causes the flicker. Some schemes allow you to render even father ahead, with triple buffering and the like, where your always rending two frames ahead. Tearing is much harder to fix.

Answer (score 1):

If you change some graphics you have to redraw the screen to display the graphic change. When you double buffer, you draw to the back buffer that is currently not visible and then when the graphic is full drawn you swap buffers. (Move the back buffer to the front) Otherwise the user will see the process of drawing the image in the form of a flicker. So to answer your question you want to double buffer anything that changes the display notably.